# Align arrows on hr

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me with a problem. I'm trying to align arrows on a `<hr>` but some arrows seems not to be working correctly.

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/Sneha_05/pen/BZdWeE)

HTML:

```
<div class = "horizontal-timeline">
    <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 20%;"></div>

    <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 60%;"></div>

    <hr>
    <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.horizontal-timeline hr {
  border: none;
  height: 6px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #29AAE3; /* old IE */
  background-color: #29AAE3; /* Modern Browsers */
  margin: 0;
}
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}
```

Comment: Add property as "display:inline" in your .arrow-up and .arrow-down classes. Since div is a block element it takes complete row when you add it. That is when second div with same name is going down. Making it inline will make it to be is same line. You may have to change position accordingly after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to position elements in relation to their container. Ditch the `<hr>`, and use `horizontal-timeline` as the line itself, then position the arrows absolutely in relation to it:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.horizontal-timeline {
  position: relative;
  height: 6px;
  background: #29AAE3;
  margin: 0;  
}

.arrow-up, .arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.arrow-up {
  top: -20px;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}

.arrow-down {
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-timeline">
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 20%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 60%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 40%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect way to implement timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

make the div elements display:inline-block; because div elements are by default block level elements which occupy full page width.

next set the position to relative and adjust accordingly..

CSS

```
    .horizontal-timeline hr
    {
        border: none;
        height: 6px;
        /* Set the hr color */
        color: #29AAE3; /* old IE */
        background-color: #29AAE3; /* Modern Browsers */
        margin: 0;
    }
    .arrow-up {
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 


border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top:4px;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class = "horizontal-timeline">
                <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 20%;"></div>

                <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>

                <hr>
                <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
                <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
            </div>
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Just add 3 css to `.arrow-up` class

```
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
top:4px;
```

And 1 css to `.arrow-down` class

```
display:inline-block;
```

and in HTML modify `margin-left` like below

```
<div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 20%;"></div>
<div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
<hr>
<div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
<div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
```

and you will get your output

Answer (score 0):

You should add a property to parent `position:relative;`
Children  `display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;`.
Add `top: 10px;` to `.arrow-up` class.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwzmyz)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `position` css property, when you want to place elements relative to each other in a web page. Here they appear in different heights because the divisions cant overlap
Mainly you will need to make use of the `position:relative` value.
Find more information about CSS propery `position` **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)**.

Here is the code snippet.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.horizontal-timeline hr {
  border: none;
  height: 6px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #29AAE3;
  /* old IE */
  background-color: #29AAE3;
  /* Modern Browsers */
  margin: 0;
}

.arrow-up {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}

.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="horizontal-timeline">
    <div class="arrow-up" style="margin-left: 10%;"></div>

    <div class="arrow-up" style="margin-left: 30%;"></div>

    <hr>
    <div class="arrow-down" style="margin-left: 30%;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" style="margin-left: 30%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: position: absolute would sure work but it hinders other elements in the web page.

Comment: Hi Sneha. Sorry, you are correct, I overlooked that part. I have edited the answer so that, it only uses `position:relative` with the help of `display:inline-block`. And added some elements so that you can see it is independent of the other elements on the page. Although do note that when using `position:relative` you need to adjust the `margin` on the divs as they are now relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS position property: make the class "horizontal-timeline" - "position:relative;", and the arrows "position: absolute;" to your timeline div  with "top:x px" as you need:
https://codepen.io/Sneha_05/pen/BZdWeE

**HTML**

```
<div class = "horizontal-timeline">
    <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 20%;"></div>            
    <div class="arrow-up" style = "margin-left: 60%;"></div>                
    <hr>
    <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 40%;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" style = "margin-left: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .horizontal-timeline hr {
   border: none;
   height: 6px;
   /* Set the hr color */
   color: #29AAE3; /* old IE */
   background-color: #29AAE3; /* Modern Browsers */
   margin: 0;
   position:relative;
   top:20px;
   }
.arrow-up {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
   position:absolute;
   }
.arrow-down {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
   position:absolute;
   top:34px;
   }
```